# Ant Zip Extracted Parent Directory

Tags: ant

I have several zip files that I need to unzip within an Ant target.  All the zip files are in the same directory, and have the same internal directory and file structure.

So I am using the following snippet to unzip all the zip files in the directory, but each zip file does not contain a parent folder at the root, so each successive zip file is unzipped and overwrites the previous files.

```
<unzip dest="C:/Program Files/Samsung/Samsung TV Apps SDK/Apps">            
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.zip"/>
    </fileset>
</unzip>
```

Is there a better way to unzip a group of files, and create a directory to unzip them to that is based on the zip file name?

So, if the zip files are:

```
1.zip
2.zip
3.zip
```

then the content of each will be extracted to:

```
1/
2/
3/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution might be to use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) 'for' and 'propertyregex' tasks to do this:

```
<for param="my.zip">
  <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.zip" />
  <sequential>
    <propertyregex property="my.zip.dir"
              input="@{my.zip}"
              regexp="(.*)\..*"
              select="\1"
              override="yes" />
    <unzip src="@{my.zip}" dest="${my.zip.dir}" />
  </sequential>
</for>
```

The 'propertyregex' strips the `.zip` extension from the zip file name to use as the target directory name.

Comment: Yea, that's what I ended up going with.  I was hoping to not have to use ant-contrib, but in this case it's probably the most straightforward way.

Answer (score -1):

Without ant-contrib:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169523/957081

```
<!-- Get the path of the war file. I know the file name pattern in this case -->
<path id="warFilePath">
    <fileset dir="./tomcat/webapps/">
        <include name="myApp-*.war"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<property name="warFile" refid="warFilePath" />

<!-- Get file name without extension -->
<basename property="warFilename" file="${warFile}" suffix=".war" />

<!-- Create directory with the same name as the war file name -->
<mkdir dir="./tomcat/webapps/${warFilename}" />

<!-- unzip war file -->
<unwar dest="./tomcat/webapps/${warFilename}">
    <fileset dir="./tomcat/webapps/">
        <include name="${warFilename}.war"/>    
    </fileset>
</unwar>
```

Comment: This solution only works if warFilePath refers to exactly 1 file. The OP asked how to extract several files.