# Unwar multiple archives into separate named directories

Tags: java, loops, ant

Is there a way of doing the same task as in this question's answer

[Ant unzip/unwar with the same directory name as the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167711/ant-unzip-unwar-with-the-same-directory-name-as-the-file-name)

but for multiple .war files, without using ant-contrib?  I need to extract the binaries for a number of .war files that are built on another server and copied to the machine running ant, so that I can run findbugs on them.  The reasons are obscure and political, and I have no control over them, but one thing I am not able to do is use ant-contrib.  I have no control over the server running ant, and have to get many approvals to ask for software to be installed.

I understand that this code will build a file set, but assumes only one file will be found and extracts the first name in the set.  Is there a non-ant-contrib way of iterating over the set, or possibly modifying the names in the set and passing that to a "mkdir" type command?  I would still need to access each .war file name to pass to "unwar".  I am an Ant beginner, but have programmed other scripting languages, and if need be I can probably cobble something together in "sh" but I'd prefer to leverage as much as possible from the Ant toolset.

Answer (score 0):

ANT is not a programming language and therefore has no native looping mechanism. This is why extensions like [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) are popular. Personally I would highly recommend installing the [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) extension.

In the absence of external plugins, a trick that can used is a XSLT transformation which generates an ANT file that is dynamically executed. Examples are given in the following answers:

- [iterate int xml file using ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528653/iterate-int-xml-file-using-ant/11529845#11529845)
- [Use pure Ant to search if list of files exists and take action based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395627/use-pure-ant-to-search-if-list-of-files-exists-and-take-action-based-on-conditio/22415997#22415997)

Finally have you considered Javascript? The required jars come bundled in the latest JVMs. See:

- [Iterate over for loop with fixed amount of iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265016/iterate-over-for-loop-with-fixed-amount-of-iterations/)